# Pivot on multiple columns based on single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in my SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
Provider  ContractID  Department    StDate       EndDate
========================================================
10001     CTR456        IT           1/1/2012     12/1/2014
10001     CT346        Account      4/1/2014     9/9/2014 
10002     CT88R01        IT           2/1/2012     2/1/2013
10003     C23TR01        IT           3/2/2012     1/1/2099
10003     C4TR02        Health       3/2/2012     1/1/2099
10003     CT56R03       Security     3/2/2012     1/1/2099
```

How can i achieve the below output using Pivot or any other method.

```
Provider Contract1 Dept1 StDt1 EndDt2   Contract2 Dept2 StDate2 EndDt2 Contract3 Dept3 StDate3 EndDt3
=====================================================================================================
10001    CTR456     IT    1/1/12 12/1/14 CT346    Accont 4/1/14 9/9/14   NULL      NULL NULL   NULL
10002    CT88R01    IT    1/1/12 12/1/14 NULL     NULL   NULL   NULL     NULL      NULL NULL   NULL
10003    C23TR01    IT    1/1/12 12/1/14 C4TR02   Health 3/2/14 1/1/99  CT56R03   Secu 3/2/14 1/1/99
```

I appreciate if anybody solve this issue.

Comment: @user1459624 - "give me the code" questions are usually not well received by the community. You should add the code you have tried, and state where you are having trouble.

Comment: will there be only maximum three contracts per provider?

Comment: Also provide schema and data sample via [SQLFiddle] http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
DECLARE @colList varchar(max)

--create dynamic list of columns
SELECT @colList = 
STUFF
(
  (
   SELECT + ',' + 
   quotename(colName +  CAST(CAST(REPLACE(ContractID,'CTR','') AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR))
   FROM Tab1
   CROSS APPLY
   (
     SELECT 1 As Ord, 'Contract' ColName UNION ALL
     SELECT 2 As Ord, 'Dept' UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 As Ord, 'StDt' UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 As Ord, 'EndDt' 
   ) v 
    GROUP BY colName,Ord,  CAST(CAST(REPLACE(ContractID,'CTR','') AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR)
    ORDER BY CAST(CAST(REPLACE(ContractID,'CTR','') AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR), Ord
   for xml path(''), type
  ).value('/','varchar(max)'),1,1,''
)

--unpivot columns into rows and then apply pivot
SET @sql
= '
SELECT Provider, ' + @colList + ' 
FROM
(
   SELECT Provider, ColVal,
   colName +  CAST(CAST(REPLACE(ContractID,''CTR'','''') AS INTEGER) AS VARCHAR) ColName
   FROM Tab1
   CROSS APPLY
   (
     SELECT ContractId As ColVal, ''Contract'' ColName UNION ALL
     SELECT Department, ''Dept'' UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(StDate AS VARCHAR), ''StDt'' UNION ALL
     SELECT CAST(EndDate AS VARCHAR), ''EndDt'' 
   ) v 
) A
PIVOT
(
   MAX(ColVal) FOR ColName IN (' + @colList + ')
) P1 '


EXEC(@sql)
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/418d5/34)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply.my coontractid is a 10 digit number, it is not exact like CTR01,CTR02...